# Error on line 2, column 5: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?

Tags: flutter

```
name: gcrs
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  floating_search_bar: ^0.3.0    
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_search_bar: ^2.1.0
  adobe_xd: ^2.0.0+1
  http: ^0.13.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter    

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/font/
    - assets/img/
```

```
Error on line 2, column 5: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
  ╷
2 │ name: gcrs
  │     ^
  ╵
```

How to fix this error?
It doesn't work after pushing to github.
It worked when I test before commit.
But it became error after pushing.
Is there anything wrong on my pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Comment your GitHub repo here

Comment: Are you repeating name, description and other details at bottom of pubspec.yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly committed your `merge conflict` while resolution.

Replace your `pubsec.yaml` file with this content.

Also, be sure to use `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` if you want `sound null safety` in `Flutter` and use `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` if you want to disable `sound null safety`.

```
name: gcrs
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  floating_search_bar: ^0.3.0    
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_search_bar: ^2.1.0
  adobe_xd: ^2.0.0+1
  http: ^0.13.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter    

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/font/
    - assets/img/

  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
```